# Kernel Error [Failed to start the kernel]

Tags: python, kernel, jupyter

I'm new to the jupyter notebook. try to make new envy, but it just produces kernel error.

I've been tried to install new kernel but has nothing to do with it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
    kernel_name=self.kernel_name
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Hawarie\Anaconda3\envs\hawarie_env\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 102, in secure_write
    with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o600), mode) as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Hawarie\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-be38d53a-3dcf-4aca-8395-93f556611cac.json'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your log it says:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'C:\\Users\\Hawarie\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-be38d53a-3dcf-4aca-8395-
93f556611cac.json'
```

I assume you are using Windows, have you tried running Anaconda as Administrator?

Comment: I'm really surprised that it is work as easy as that, why'd I never thought about it in advance. thanks anyway